# Logstash mixed log parsing

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I'm processing log files through Logstash that have single-line messages and multi-line messages of various patterns, I'd like to read the multi-line messages as single-line messages and the single-line messages as is.

Currently, I'm using the below Logstash config, but this is creating duplicate messages in the output. Moreover, for every new pattern of multi-line messages, I need to create a separate input with its own multi-line codec. Is there any way to combine all these patterns into a single input?

Sample Logstash Config File:

```
input {
#Using a single log file as input, containing multiple multi-line messages (patterns) and single line messages
  file {
    codec => multiline {
          pattern => pattern1
          ....
        }
  }

  file {
    codec => multiline {
          pattern => pattern2
          ....
        }
  }

  file {
   #Single line message processing 
  }

}

filter {
#Contains filters and parsing for both multi-line and single line messages 
}

output {
#To json file
}
```

What I would like to do:

```
input {
  file {
    codec => multiline {
          pattern => pattern1,pattern2,....
          ....
          }
  }
  file {
    #Single line messages input
    #May not be needed
  }
```

}

Also, can you process single-line messages with a multiline codec input in Logstash?

Comment: You can have only one pattern in the multiline codec. You have multiple multilines patterns in the same file? Also, how is this duplicating your messages? Are you reading the same file in different inputs?

Comment: I fixed the issue by combining the multi-line patterns in a single codec. Reading the same file in different inputs was causing the duplication, so I modified the multiple multilines patterns to work in a single multiline codec and parsed the log file.